# Как во время дебага приложения на С++ сделать "Step In" в стороннюю библиотеку?

Tags: c++, отладка

Есть приложение на С++11, использует autotools. 
Есть библиотека на С++11, использует cmake. 
Библиотека устанавливается вручную в систему через make install, сборка с CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug и линкуется к приложению как `-la` (файл `liba.a`)

Когда я дебажу приложение в CLion, и делаю step inside function этой библиотеки, я вижу только ASM инструкции (из `liba.a`).

При условии, что я могу указать путь к исходникам этой библиотеки, как можно заставить CLion показать исходники вместо ASM во время дебага?

Comment: тут надо не путь к исходникам указывать, а собрать эту библиотеку без оптимизации и с отладочными символами. make install лучше избегать

Comment: в дополнение к вышесказанному: инструкция `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` не устанавливает флаг `-g` для компилятора, так что вам нужно прописать его либо в `target_compile_options`, либо, что ИМХО лучше, указать подобным образом: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g")`

Comment: Собрал с `-g` и -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug, установил через make install, проверил чтоб линковалась именно версия с дебаг символами, всё равно CLion не показывает исходники.

Comment: @warchantua если вы действительно собрали библиотеку с `-g` и после этого собрали свое приложение именно с этой библиотекой, то значит это проблема IDE